# Get start date of week using datepart

Tags: sql

I have a table with 2 columns - Date, ItemsSold. I have the following query

```
Select datepart(week, [Date]) as WeekNo, SUM([ItemsSold]) as Total From [table] 
group by datepart(week, [Date])
```

This gives the following output

```
WeekNo   Total
3         20
4         30
```

What I actually need is an output as follows

```
WeekOf          Total
11 Jan 2015      20
18 Jan 2015      30
```

How do I get the start date of the week that datepart returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL server, something like this:

```html
declare @StartDate as datetime = '1/1/' + cast(datepart(year,getdate()) as char(4))
declare @StartofYear as datetime = dateadd(day,(datepart(dw,@startdate)*-1)+1,@StartDate)

Select datepart(week, [Date]) as WeekNo, SUM([ItemsSold]) as Total, dateadd(day,(@WeekNo-1)*7,@StartofYear) as WeekOf
From [table] 
group by datepart(week, [Date])
```